# too many collisions in random number generator collision test

Tags: c++, for-loop, random, generator, gsl

I'm expecting lKolizji variable to be around 128, but it's much higher for large ammount of generated numbers and "boxes". The results for smaller numbers are good. I have no idea why is this happening. Here is my code with example parameters that give wrong answer. Example of good result(around 128) is                   int lPrzedzialow=1000000;
int iLiczb = 16000;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
//Random number
   unsigned int seed=2596524;
   gsl_rng * r=gsl_rng_alloc (gsl_rng_mt19937);
   gsl_rng_set(r,seed);
   gsl_rng_env_setup();
//Parameters
   int lPrzedzialow=10000000000;//number of boxes
   int iLiczb = 1600000;//number of random numbers
   int z,lKolizji=0;//lKolizji holds collision number
   vector<int> lwKomorkach(iLiczb);//number of boxes of random numbers
   long double dlPrzedzialu=1./(lPrzedzialow);
//number of box of a random number 
   for (int i = 0; i < iLiczb; i++)
   {
       lwKomorkach[i] = floor((gsl_rng_uniform (r)/dlPrzedzialu));
   }
//sorting
   sort( lwKomorkach.begin(), lwKomorkach.end() );
//how many collisions
   for(z=0;z<=iLiczb-1;z++)
   {
       if(lwKomorkach[z+1]==lwKomorkach[z]){lKolizji++;}
   }
  double pdf[lKolizji];
  pdf[0]=exp(-128);
  double spdf=exp(-128);
  for(int h=1;h<lKolizji;h++){
     pdf[h]=pdf[h-1]*128./(h);
     spdf+=pdf[h];
  }
  double pwyzsze=1.-spdf;
  cout<<endl<<lKolizji<<" "<<spdf<<"  "<<pwyzsze<<endl;
  gsl_rng_free (r);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Give some parameter-output examples ("good" cases; "bad" cases). I would expect a number of 254 for the parameters above. So maybe you can explain how you come to expect 128?

Comment: good output : 133   0.66   0.34, bad output: 448   1   3*10^(-16). We want number of collision 128. Equation for this 128=n^2/2l where n is number of random numbers and l is period number. then 260l=n^2 we do a trick l=s^2 16s=n and when s=1000 then l(lPrzedzialow) is 10^6 and lLiczb=16*1000=16000.

Comment: I'm talking about the definition of ```lPrzedzialow``` and ```iLiczb``` here. These are inputs, ```lKolizji``` the output. So where is the input in your comment? Why does it not follow the form/convention of the code?

Comment: Even though you generate random values as a `long double` between 0 and whatever the truncated value of `lPrzedzialow` is, these values are being stored in a `vector` of `int` values, which quantizes the results from the full precision of `long double` into integer values, with a big loss of entropy.

Comment: changing vector type to long long int changes sytuation a bit for better, but  still that's not it

Answer (score 1):

This number: 10000000000, is too big for a 32 bit int. In fact, it is equivalent to 1,410,065,408, approx 1/7th of the size you believe it to be.

Comment: so should i use for example long long int? then my program crashes before it even starts to count

Comment: @Sarah Then check your compiler on types supported. And for the extreme cases: there is always [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @Sarah, you can try that, but take into account that the larger that number gets, the less precise your reciprocal calculation will get, especially as long double may or may not be equivalent to a plain double depending on your platform.

Comment: i just tried every type and it gives the same result or doesn't work at all